# How do you create a static library in XCode and reference from 3rd party project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to create a new target in project SDKTest.xcodeproj (say target is named lib_SDK.a) which contains all of the files in SDKTest.xcodeproj. I would then like to be able to import the lib_SDK.a file in my third party application called Client.xcodeproj and instanciate objects from that library, say an object called ScanMe.h

I am currently doing this by creating a project reference in Client.xcodeproj. The problem is that the lib_SDK.a file is red in Client.xcodeproj...perhaps I haven't created the library correctly? I am also unsure how to verify that all the headers are included in this lib_SDK.a library.

Can anyone walk me through steps? I have scoured blogs/tutorials but am having problems still!

Answer (score 1):

There are several descriptions on the net about how to do it, e.g:

[Creating a Static Library for iPhone](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html)

[Build iPhone static library with XCode](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=808)